# Accepting a grammar in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, grammar

This is a lab assignment I am stuck on.

I need to accept this grammar `(ab)*b`, which basically means any number of "ab" and ending with b.

I have written this code but somehow, it checks only the first 2 letters.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum track {true, false};

void main()

{
    clrscr();
    char*str;
    enum track track_pos, track_pos_2;
    cout<<"enter the string: ";
    cin>>str;
    int len=strlen(str);
    cout<<"length of the string is "<<len;
    getch();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len; i++)
    {
        ++str;
        cout<<"loop"<<i;
        if(*str=='a' && i%2==0)
        {
            cout<<"\nchecking a...";
            track_pos=true;
            cout<<"\na.check";
            ++str;
            if (*str=='b')
                {
                cout<<"\nchecking b...";
                track_pos=true;
                cout<<"\nb.check";
            }
            else{
                track_pos=false;
                cout<<"\nb.uncheck";
            }
        }

    }

    if(*str=='b')
        track_pos_2=true;
    else
        track_pos_2=false;

    if(track_pos==true && track_pos_2==true)
        cout<<"\nThe string is accpeted.";
    else
        cout<<"\nThe string is rejected.";

    getch();
    cout<<"\n\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ";
    char ch;
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
        main();

}
```

Comment: it's the first time I see a recursive `main` :-)

Comment: it was the easiest way out...:)

Comment: It's quite common in obfuscated C code competition entries

Comment: I suspect this is using a really ancient C++ compiler. The enum kind of gives it away.

Comment: Yeah, like `<iostream.h>` and no `std::` prefixes. <looks back the the code> <shudders>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to regret this, but each time I look at this question I see something else wrong with your code. Here is the line by line. I've probably missed a lot.

The correct name for this header is "iostream", not "iostream.h" - the ".h" version is deprecated. Similarly, use "string", not "string.h" in modern C++, and use the modern STL string classes.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

As pointed out, don't do this. You have redefined the standard `bool` type to have the opposite value from the standard types. I don't even know that this is legal.

```
enum track {true, false};
```

The return value of the `main` function is `int`, not `void`.

```
void main()    
{
    clrscr();
```

Do you know what a buffer overflow is? You have defined `str` as a pointer here, with no allocated memory, and you write to that undefined bit of memory a bit later on. This is undefined behaviour, and you are pretty much guaranteed to crash. I recommend, you should defined `str` as a `std::string` - this will nicely avoid the buffer overflow, and it has many useful methods that you can use in your program.

```
    char*str;
    enum track track_pos, track_pos_2;
    cout<<"enter the string: ";
```

This is the buffer overflow right here. You are writing to who knows what area of memory.

```
    cin>>str;
```

If `str` was a `std::string` - you would do `size_t len=str.length()`;

```
    int len=strlen(str);
    cout<<"length of the string is "<<len;
```

It's probably not a good idea to mix console IO functions like this with iostreams functions - there are some buffering issues that can lead to difficulties.

```
    getch();
```

Declare `i` in the body of the loop, since you aren't using it again. Like so:

```
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) etc...

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len; i++)
    {
```

Instead of using poiter arithmetic, since you are keeping track of the index of the current character in `i`, just use that and treat `str` as an array. This way, you don't have to keep `str` in synch with `i` all of the way through. This is the cause the bug you are reporting, by the way.

```
        ++str;
        cout<<"loop"<<i;
```

You should change this to:

```
        if (str[i]=='a' && i%2==0)
```

(That works even if `str` is a `std::string` by the way, unlike the pointer arithmetic version).

```
        if(*str=='a' && i%2==0)
        {
```

You really should drop out at some point, if you figure out that the string doesn't match, then there is no point going on to the end of the string.

```
                cout<<"\nchecking a...";
```

I don't favour status flags like this - your code is partly hard to understand because of the proliferation of these flags, you cannot keep track of the proper behaviour. The name `track_pos` is not mnemonic, that makes it hard to work out what it is meant to signify without detailed study of the code.

I would recommend that you would refactor your code inside the body of the for loop to call a function, the purpose of which is simply to match a single group of "ab" - this function could return true if it did, and false if it did not.

```
                track_pos=true;
                cout<<"\na.check";
```

Note that since we are dealing with the buffer overflow mentioned before, you are iterating undefined memory. Also note that you did not increment `i` here.

```
                ++str;
                if (*str=='b')
                        {
                        cout<<"\nchecking b...";
                        track_pos=true;
                        cout<<"\nb.check";
                }
                else{
                        track_pos=false;
                        cout<<"\nb.uncheck";
                }
        }

    }
```

When we get to here, according to your for loop, we have iterated the whole string, so we must be looking past the end of the string (even ignoring the buffer overflow) so there is no possible way this test can succeed. In short, your for loop must be going too far.

```
    if(*str=='b')
        track_pos_2=true;
    else
        track_pos_2=false;

    if(track_pos==true && track_pos_2==true)
```

Should I mention the spelling mistake?

```
        cout<<"\nThe string is accpeted.";
    else
        cout<<"\nThe string is rejected.";

    getch();
    cout<<"\n\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ";
    char ch;
    cin>>ch;
```

If you refactor your code into appropriate sub-routines, you will find the structure of the program takes care of itself. Note that calling `main` recursively is not strictly illegal, but it is kind of weird and has an obvious vulnerability that will lead to an eventual stack overflow, if the program never exits.

```
    if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
        main();

}
```

Comment: "vulnerability that will lead to an eventual stack overflow" -- his program has already led him to stack overflow.  Dot com.

Comment: I gotta admire the persistance of the fellow who posted this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Implement a simple state machine. It has these states:

- 0 = start
- 1 = 'received a of (ab)'
- 2 = 'received b of (ab)'
- 3 = 'received final b'
- -1 = error, invalid grammar

Then you just need a function like this:

```
int nextState(int currentState, char inputChar) {
  if (currentState == 0 && inputChar == 'a') return 1; // handled string is "a"
  if (currentState == 0 && inputChar == 'b') return 3; // handled string is "b"
  if (currentState == 1 && inputChar == 'b') return 2; // handled string is "ab", or "abab", or ...
  if (currentState == 2 && inputChar == 'a') return 1; // handled string is "aba", or "ababa", or ...
  if (currentState == 2 && inputChar == 'b') return 3; // handled string is "abb", or "ababb", or ...
  return -1;
}
```

Iterate this "state machine" over your input chars, starting with state 0, and if you end up in state 3, your input is valid.

```
int isValid(char* inputString) {
  int state = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<str_len(inputString); i++) {
    state = nextState(state, inputString[i]);
  }

  return (state == 3);
}
```

Comment: Use an enum for the different states, this will make the code better readable and maintainable. Before you start coding design the state machine on paper, to make sure all the different state transitions are covered.

Comment: just as a shortcut you might want to check the final b first.

Comment: You could turn this into a multidimensional array of possible input values and the resultant state and make it even cleaner.  Then it would be:
return output[currentState][inputChar];
This becomes less useful if you have a lot of inputs though but it would be fine here and would let you add more states easily without needing code changes.  I liked 1800INFORMATION's answer but this solution is my favorite.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I wanted to give an as-simple-as-possible answer. Of course I'd have used an enum in a real application.

Comment: Your state machine is wrong, it accepts `(ab)+b` instead of `(ab)*b`. Remove state 0 and make 2 the initial state.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit on what the above code does...i remember reading abt these state machines in my previous sem. cant really make out much from it?

Comment: I added an example loop to use it. Basically your machine can be in a set of states, and it can move from one state to another based on inputs - in your case characters of a string. When you use state machines for accepting grammar, you usually have a special trap state (in the example -1): a machine never moves out from it, and moves into it for any unexpected input. Furthermore you have accept states (3 in the example): if at the end of the string the machine is in this state, the string is valid; otherwise it is not.

Answer (score 4):

Things wrong with your code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

should be:

```
#include <iostream>
```

The following is a non-standard (and very old) header:

```
#include <conio.h>
```

The following is illegal - true and false are reserved words.

```
enum track {true, false};
```

In C and C++, main must return an int:

```
void main()
```

Non standard function:

```
clrscr();
```

No memory allocated to this pointer:

```
char*str;
```

which is then used here - result undefined behaviour:

```
cin>>str;
```

Illegal call to main:

```
    main();
```

I suspect you are using a very old and obsolete C++ compiler. You should replace it with something like MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this!

```
enum track {true, false};
```

Here your true is equal to 0 and false is equal to one! When you later assign track_pos, you may get the wrong value! (Because when converting bool to int, true converts to 1 and false converts to 0.)

That's only a guess though.  Maybe it's something else that matters.

Comment: Wait, what? Can you even *do* that?

Comment: Since it's a complete looks-like-C++ program, what amit has posted, It compiles on his machine with his crazy compiler!  So I'm just trying to guess what his crazy compiler could do with it.